# How do I track a goal path over multiple visits?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

My sales cycle is measured in weeks.  A typical user behavior pattern looks like this:

1. Finds the site via organic, cpc, or referral
2. Browses the content for awhile.
3. Returns a few days later, browses the content for awhile
4. Returns a few days later, browses the content for awhile
5. Converts.

Google Analytics shows all my conversions as "direct traffic", i.e. because the converting visit starts from a bookmark or a URL type-in.

What software or service can I use to tell me which traffic source in step 1 that users ultimately convert with best in step 5?

What software or service can I use to tell me which content in steps 2-4 (i.e. on prior visits) has the biggest impact on version rate in step 5?

Answer (score 2):

Great question. It has been a longstanding issue on Google that it defaults to ['last touch attribution'](http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=last%20touch%20attribution), meaning the conversion is attributed to the last channel a visitor arrives from.

In the new version of Google Analytics, Google introduced [Multi-Channel Funnels](https://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1191180), to show you "how your marketing channels (i.e. sources of traffic to your website) work together to create sales and conversions."

> In the reports, channels are credited according to the roles they play
>   in conversions-- how often they assisted and/or completed sales and
>   conversions. The Assisted Conversions report shows how many sales and
>   conversions each channel initiated, assisted and completed, and the
>   value of those conversions and sales.
>
> The Top Conversion Paths report shows the conversion paths that your
>   customers took on their way to purchase. Time Lag and Path Length
>   reports show how long (in days and in interactions) it took for
>   visitors to ultimately become customers.

You can read the full documentation on Multi-Channel Funnels here:

- https://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1191180

There is also a good overview video on the [GoogleAnalytics Youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/googleanalytics) here:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZ2RbGsuy3U

---

To access the new version of GA, log into your account. You should see a link in the top nav bar named 'New Version'.

If you don't see the new version link, you might need to opt-in for it here:

- http://www.google.com/analytics/analytics-funnels.html

---

**Update:** Multi-channel funnels are now available for all users of Google Analytics:

- http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/08/introducing-multi-channel-funnels.html