# See how one goal leads to another (i.e., how often downloading the demo leads to purchasing)

Tags: google-analytics, conversions

I have two goals set up for my site in Google Analytics: one to download the demo of my software, and the other to buy the full version. I'm having trouble getting statistics on how often the download leads to a purchase.

This seems like something the multi-channel funnel is perfect for (as in [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18470/how-do-i-track-a-goal-path-over-multiple-visits))---I expect that it takes multiple visits for the demo download to convert into an order. However, I can't seem to narrow down the multi-channel funnel data into only those that have one goal followed by another.

If it matters, I'm tracking the ordering action as a page view (i.e., someone views the "Thanks for ordering" page) and the demo download as an action (which fires when someone clicks the "download" button).

**EDIT**: I have a funnel set up for this (which has the demo download as a required first step, followed by the steps in the multi-page purchasing funnel). However, as far as I can tell, this does not display what I want, since I expect the purchasing step to occur on a separate visit. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: In your Goal settings have you checked the box for `Use Funnel` "A funnel is a series of pages leading up to the goal destination. For example, the funnel may include steps in your checkout process that lead you to the thank you page (goal)." While you may have Goals setup it may not be checked to work with a Funnel

Comment: I do have a funnel set up (with downloading the demo as a required first step, and the ordering process later), but I don't think it shows what I'm looking for. As I understand it, the funnel shows people who, in the same visit, download the demo, then order the product (which I expect to be a tiny number compared to the number of people who do this over multiple visits).

Comment: If you want to test the multi-funnel view. Turn off Google instant search, run a keyword search for your product click through to the page and download it. Then wait about 10 minutes and refresh the multi-channel funnel views to see if it picked up the Organic search as the first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. By associating an event in Google Analytics with each goal (e.g., downloading the demo), I can go to the Content > Events reporting to see the ecommerce conversion rate associated with each goal.